# $window .on("scroll") working only in last directive it's called on

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple directive that sets or removes classes when scrolling near an element. I'm using a callback for the `scroll` event on `$window`, but the problem is that it's only working for the last directive only.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oij46REbOYTLh0zUrDTj?p=preview)

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box hidden" on-scroll-class="{add: 'large', remove: 'hidden'}"></div>
    <div class="box hidden" on-scroll-class="{add: 'large', remove: 'hidden'}"></div>
    <div class="box hidden" on-scroll-class="{add: 'large', remove: 'hidden'}"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("onScrollClass", ["$window", function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        onScrollClass: "@",
        onScrollClassReverse: "@",
        onScrollOffset: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var reverse = angular.isDefined(scope.onScrollClassReverse) ?
                scope.onScrollClassReverse : false;

              var offset = angular.isDefined(scope.onScrollOffset) ?
                scope.onScrollOffset : 150;

              var classToAddObj = scope.$eval(scope.onScrollClass);
              var classToAdd;
              var classToRemove = null;

              if (angular.isObject(classToAddObj)) {
                classToAdd = classToAddObj.add;
                classToRemove = classToAddObj.remove;
              } else {
                classToAdd = classToAddObj;
              }

              $element = $(element);
              $($window).on("scroll", function() {
                  console.log($element);
                  console.log($element.offset().top);
                  if (this.pageYOffset >= $element.offset().top - offset) {
                      $element.addClass(classToAdd);
                      $element.removeClass(classToRemove);

                  } else if (reverse) {
                      $element.addClass(classToRemove);
                      $element.removeClass(classToAdd);
                  }
                });

          }
      }
}]);
```

CSS

```
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: .3;
}

.large {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transition: all .5s ease;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Angular.

You are setting the variable `$element` without declaring it is a variable.
due to Javascript prototypal inheritance, it will try to find that variable in the prototype chain.
and in case it won't find it, it will treat it as a global variable.

Thats why only the last directive works for you, it's overriding the `$element` variable each time.

Just add `var` before `$element`, and remember always to declare a variable using the `var` keyword (or `let` (ES 2015) is even better).

Comment: Awesome, you rock!! I was so frustrated, now I feel stupid, LOL. Thanks.